# jQuery doesn't clear TextBox and $.get() doesn't pass parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a list of items on a page, capable of being filtered by a textbox (similar to the MVC tutorial).  I have a button which I would like to *clear* the text in the TextBox and call the controller function which will then bring the list of items back to its initial, unifiltered state.

**The problem I am having** is twofold: my jQuery code which clears the text of the TextBox does not clear the TextBox of the search term, and my jQuery code which explicitly passes in the empty string as a parameter to my controller does not pass in that parameter.

For example:

1. Page has a list of stuff.
2. I type "fart" in the filter box, and hit enter.
3. The page reloads, and the list of stuff is now filtered by "fart".
4. I press the Clear button.
5. The page reloads, but the list of stuff is still filtered by "fart", and the TextBox is not cleared.

I suspect this is all due to the TextBox not being cleared, but I honestly have no idea.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var modelitem = new MyThing();
}

@model IEnumerable<MyModel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fart() {
        $('#reset').click(function() {
            $('#filterTerm').val('');
            $.get("SelectionSummary/Index", { filterTerm: '' })
        });
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="input-group center-block">
        <h3 class="text-center">Selections</h3>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.TextBox("filterTerm", null, new
                   {
                        @id = "filterTerm",
                        @class = "form-control col-md-offset-2",
                        @placeholder = "Filter"
                   })
        <input id="reset" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="reset" onclick="fart"/>
    </div>
}

<br />
@if (Model != null && Model.Any())
{
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-offset-2" style="width:62%">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <br />
        <table class="table table-striped text-center">

            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => modelitem.NameLabel)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => modelitem.Thing)
                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var thing in Model.OrderBy(g => g.Name))
            {
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.ActionLink(thing.Name, "Detail", new { selectionSearchTerm = thing.Name })
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => thing.Other.Name)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
}
else
{
    <h4 class="text-center">No results</h4>
}
```

**SelectionSummaryController.cs**

```
 public ActionResult Index(string filterTerm = "")
 {
        var stuff= m_repo.GetAllStuff();
        if (stuff.IsNullOrEmpty()) // extension method
        {
            return View();
        }

        if (filterTerm.HasValue()) // extension method
        {
            stuff= stuff.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(filterTerm));
        }

        return View(stuff.ToList());
 }
```

Comment: `$.get("SelectionSummary/Index", { filterTerm: '' })` is only calling the server. Your not doing anything with the view you returned (i.e. updating the DOM) and your not cancelling the default submit so its probably calling the server twice

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in using `HasValue.` I would change to:

```
public ActionResult Index(string filterTerm = "")
 {
        var stuff= m_repo.GetAllStuff();
        if (stuff.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            return View();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterTerm))
        {
            stuff= stuff.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(filterTerm));
        }

        return View(stuff.ToList());
 }
```

Furthermore, your javascript doesn't make sense. Why are you putting a click event handler on a button when you click the button? Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fart() {
            $('#filterTerm').val('');
            $.get("SelectionSummary/Index", { filterTerm: '' })
    }
</script>
```

That being said, I am not sure why you are even using that ajax get. You aren't doing anything with the data.

Comment: I should have put it as a comment; `HasValue()` is an extension method which wraps the inverse of `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Comment: Have you stepped through that code and made sure it tests the way you would expect?

Comment: > Have you stepped through that code and made sure it tests the way you would expect?

Yes.

Regarding the JS, I'm just very new when it comes to front-end stuff.  What would be the best way to call a Controller method with a new filter term?

Comment: Is that block of html inside `<form>` tags?

Comment: I believe so, unless the `@Html.BeginForm()` doesn't do that.

Comment: could you edit your post so that that part of the view is included?

Comment: Edited to include the whole view.